# WInforms app for comparing folders and files

Tags: c#, winforms, compare

I am developing an win forms application for that will compare two folder for its contents.
i do not want to compare just file names and their length.
if there are differences between two files i want to show them to user.
i am done with UI part, i am also able to get folder contents but now i am little confused between how to compare contents of files. what should i use to compare contents ?
also how can i show the 'difference' between two files to user.
any suggestions would be thankful.

Comment: Which type of files will be there in folders?............txt,.doc...etc?

Comment: Do you need to be able to also compare files in subdirectories or is this strictly done in a single layer?

Comment: And when you say differences, do you actually need to parse the contents of the file, or could something like comparing MD5 checksums suffice?

Comment: Also, depending on the file type, there may be no plausible of _showing_ an end user the specific differences. For example, a Windows execuatable (.exe), the only thing you could really show the user is the different checksums or the varied bytes, which doesn't really provide them much information.

Comment: You can use DirectoryInfo, FileInfo etc. classes which provides a wide range of properties. You can compare each property. Also If it is folder, you can use recursion for multilevel comparison. However you should explain what exactly your app is gonna compare, i.e. its purpose.

Comment: It's also not clear what you're actually comparing. Are you comparing the contents of two directories to see if they contain the same files, the contents of two files to see if they're _effectively_ the same file, or both?

Comment: @Leon Newswanger : yes, it should compare files in sub directories also and not in Topmost directory only. also folder can contain any file formats like xml, doc, ini, csv etc. but not dlls and exe. i want to compare contents of files and if there are any differences, mark them with some different color.

Comment: So in other words basic formats, nothing compressed or using 16+ bit encoding etc? Are you comparing two different directories, or entering a single directory and checking all of the files within that and it's subdirectories? And does your checking need to be able to take files in the subdirectories and compare them the whole way to root? Sorry, that should be the last bit I need to figure out the best approach.